# Run jQuery AJAX call when previous AJAX call fail due to connection was unexpactly closed

Tags: ajax, http, jquery

I know about error in application running on server and invoked operation disconnect all HTTP clients. I need to invoke this functionality on the server but I'm not able to fix the error.
Here is my server code:

```
<?php
// file: run_script.php
shell_exec('close_all_HTTP_connections_error '.$_REQUEST['params']);
?>
```

I'm trying to find workaround via AJAX call, I know that call fails, but user doesn't see error like `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. My problem is that I need to do another call to the server (which doesn't fail normaly). The second call is not send to server because previous call fail I guess.
Here is my jQuery AJAX call:

```
function sendData(url, step) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    url: url,
    headers: { // I try it without this also
      'Connection' : 'close'
    },
    data: {
      'params' : 'bla bla'
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      if (step < 2) {
        sendData('another.php', step+1);
      }
      else {
        console.log("done");
        // go forward
      }
    },
    dataType: 'html'
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   sendData('run_script.php', 1);
});
```

Here is my screen shot from Chrome inspector:

[image]

And HTTP Requests:

run_script.php:

```
POST http://?????.com/test/run_script.php HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://?????.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.22 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/19.0.1049.3 Safari/535.22
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://?????.com/test/result.php
params:bla bla
```

another.php:

```
POST http://?????.com/test/another.php HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://?????.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.22 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/19.0.1049.3 Safari/535.22
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://?????.com/test/result.php
params:bla bla
```

There is no HTTP Response of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that task previously invoked on server restarts server. Then I need to wait before next AJAX call is invoked.

I fact I have to solve problem with server restart first, this is work-around only and not the best solution.